# Cannot connect to AWS RDS database from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have setup a free-tier account with AWS and have setup my apache server up and running.
Next I setup a RDS MySQL RDS database and tried to connect to the MySQL database using mysqli_connect() as well as mysqli() from a page running on my server on EC2. It does not connect, and after a ling time displays 504 Gateway Timeout Error.
I tried to connect to a MariaDB, still the same result.

http://ec2-3-131-135-188.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/maria.php

```
<?php 
include "../inc/dbinfo.inc"; 
$db_server = 'silkweb-maria.chwegpctvkzc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com';
if (is_file("../inc/dbinfo.inc"))
{ 
    echo "Connecting to     " .$db_server .  ' ' . DB_USERNAME .   '  '. DB_PASSWORD;
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($db_server, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "File does not exist";
}
?>
```

I tried to connect using mysql command through ssh,

```
 mysql -h silkweb.chwegpctvkzc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com  -P 3306 -u xxxxx -p
```

And I get the following error after about a minute

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'silkweb.chwegpctvkzc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (60)
```

Any help to fix the issue is highly appreciated.

**Update:** I am able to connect to my database instance through DBeaver from my mac.

Comment: What do the security groups look like?

Comment: For mariaDB: Inbound: IPv4 MYSQL/Aurora TCP 3306, Outbound: IPv4 All traffic All All: For MySQL DB: Inbound Rules: – All traffic All All, Outbound Rules: IPv4 All traffic All All

Comment: Are they in the same network? If not you should check a route exists for them to communicate. Also check the security groups so the EC2 has outbound rules to RDS and RDS accepts traffic from the EC2 in the corresponding ports.

Comment: Yes, EC2 and RDS are in the same region (US-East Ohio). Surprisingly, I am able to connect to the MySQL Instance from DBeaver client on my mac and able to create a database and tables. If I am able to connect to the database instance, I believe that it is up and running and most of the settings are correct. However, I am still unable to connect to it through a script running on my EC2 instance.

Comment: I notice that `silkweb.chwegpctvkzc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com` resolves to `172.31.45.152`. This is a private IP address. It would not be possible to connect to that database from your own computer on the Internet using that IP address. Did you change something? Can you confirm that you can still connect from your Mac?

Comment: Sorry. The database instance that worked is silkweb.chwegpctvkzc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com  I am still able to connect to this database from my mac. I am able to add records to a table and read them back. (This connection is to mariaDB)

Comment: Lookup Hostname: silkweb-maria.chwegpctvkzc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
Lookup IPv4 Address: 3.132.250.222

Comment: If you show the wrong DNS name in your question, then please Edit your question to correct it.

Comment: If you login to the EC2 instance and attempt to resolve the `silkweb-maria.chwegpctvkzc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com` DNS name, what IP address does it return? (This must be done from the EC2 instance, not your computer on the Internet.) Also, could you please confirm whether they are **in the same VPC** (not just same region).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited the question and corrected the hostname for my RDS instance. Yes, both EC2 and RDS instances use the same VPC. I don't know how to resolve "silkweb-maria.chwegpctvkzc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com DNS name from EC2 intance" -- please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I started playing with Inbound and Outbound rules and suddenly, I was able to connect to my database from my EC2 server. (I don't remember what changes I made.) I am attaching image of the rules. Please see if that opens any security holes or if I need make any changes to the rules.

[image: Outbound Rules]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does that mean it is now working for you? Generally, it is bad security practice to make a database accessible from the Internet. At the very least, you should configure the Inbound security group to only allow access from your own IP address and from the CIDR range of the VPC. (The pictures above don't show which IP address range CIDR is open for those rules.)

Comment: @johnRotenstein, yes it is working now. I will post a new picture of inbound security and would love to have your comments, as I am a beginner in this area.